# how to generate constructor in a enum using Lombok

Tags: java, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I want to use lombok in a enum, but I can't find the annotation to generate the constructor. I checked the Lombok manual that it shows there should be a annotion named @XArgsConstructor,but I can't find it, any advice ? thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that  "Enable annotation processing" in Settings -> Build -> Compiler -> Annotation Processor is checked?

Comment: yes, I can use other annotations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`X` in [`@XArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) is just a placeholder for `No`, `Required` or `All`.

The real annotations are `@NoArgsConstructor`, `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`. Pick one of these (I'd go for `@AllArgsConstructor` by default), and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'd want to add an example about how it should be done:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum EnumExample {
   CONSTANT("constant");

   @Getter 
   private final String value;
}
```

Have in mind that the idea behind using enums is using objects rather than static constants. This will give benefits according how to manage the constant values.